# Subclassing SCNScene in Swift - override init

Tags: swift, overriding, scenekit

I'm getting some compiler errors in Xcode 6 using Swift which I have a hard time wrapping my head around.  I'm trying to create a scene by subclassing SCNScene, but keep getting errors on the initialisers.  The basic structure of my code is:

```
class SpaceScene: SCNScene {
    override init(named: String) {
        super.init(named: named)
    }
}
```

This results in an error on line 2 with the message "Initializer does not override a designated initializer from its superclass", although SCNScene clearly has such an initialiser.  I think i'm missing something basic - any insights?

Comment: maybe you forgot to override other designated initializers (such as `initWithCoder:` since it conforms to `NSSecureCoding`)

Comment: init(named:String) is a convenience method and can not be overwritten in this manner

Answer (score 1):

On `XCode 6.1`, the following should do it:

```
class SpaceScene : SCNScene {

override init() {
    super.init()
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
}
```

Comment: For the ones like me that were still looking for a away to provide  init with named parameter on the subclass, there is no need after apply this solution. Convenience constructors are automatic made available once all designated constructors are available [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html), role 2.