# What methods do I need in custom scene class of Scenekit ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, scenekit

I have created a custom class called ScoreBoardScene that inherits from SCNScene. in the .m file I have a method that adds all the geometry to the scene called -(void)createScene. Now where do I call createScene? Like is there a certain init method? Also according to [this](https://www.weheartswift.com/introduction-scenekit-part-1/%22this%22) tutorial I need to have a nscoder method as well. So what are the two methods I need to complete the sceneview class besides all the custom methods I have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't subclass `SCNScene`.

- [Trouble subclassing SCNScene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34534743/trouble-subclassing-scnscene)
- [Subclassing SCNScene and SceneKit Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33881677/subclassing-scnscene-and-scenekit-editor)
- [Subclassing SCNScene in Swift - override init](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26287108/subclassing-scnscene-in-swift-override-init)

Instead, your `createScene` method (perhaps implemented in an Objective-C category on `SCNNode`) should return an `SCNNode` which is the root node of your scene.

For even better startup performance, you can run `createScene` once, in an auxiliary program, and then archive the scene. The archived scene can then be embedded as a resource in your final product, and even tweaked using the SceneKit editor in Xcode..